# Query For Custom Metadata Type WHERE Field = false Returning 0 Rows But Matching Record Exists

Tags: soql, custom-metadata, boolean

I'm querying my Custom Metadata Type `VRecTypeNm__mdt` using

```
SELECT Label,ProductName__c,ProductCategory__c,EuOpps__c,NaOpps__c,PhysicalCard__c
  FROM VRecTypeNm__mdt
 WHERE Label = 'CP Virtual All In One' AND PhysicalCard__c = false
```

this query returns no rows. Despite there being a matching record -

[image: Metadata Record]

But when I remove `AND PhysicalCard__c = false` from the query, this is the result

[image: Query Result]

which shows that the field's value is false so why isn't the record being retrieved when I include the PhysicalCard criteria?

Comment: Are there any extra spaces in the 'CP Virtual All In One' value in the row that are being hidden by the HTML presentation?

Comment: @KeithC no there aren't.

Comment: Just saw your "when I remove" point in the question a bit too late.

Comment: What is interesting to me is that in the first screenshot, NA Opportunities renders as an unchecked box, while Physical Card renders as blank. Is there any difference if you change the query to check "= null" instead? (There shouldn't be, but it wouldn't be first problem with metadata checkboxes: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bS6AAI)

Comment: @Jeff yes it looks like that's the answer. Once I check & uncheck the checkbox, the record is retrieved successfully. When I created the record using the Custom Metadata Loader, I didn't explicitly set the checkbox to false..

Comment: @Jeff you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is interesting to me is that in the first screenshot, NA Opportunities renders as an unchecked box, while Physical Card renders as blank. Is there any difference if you change the query to check "= null" instead?

> @Jeff yes it looks like that's the answer. Once I check & uncheck the
>   checkbox, the record is retrieved successfully. I had created the metadata records, then created the boolean field & was querying that field before I had set it's value.
>
> Alex S

**UPDATE**

Now a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkmj).

**UPDATE**

Known Issue now resolved.